# How to enable syntax highlight for script tages in .cshtml files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, razor-pages

Just started using Visual Studio 2022 and for some reason the syntax highlighting is not working correctly on `.cshtml` files:

[For example](https://i.postimg.cc/ZRXKpLbW/Screenshot-2022-06-27-173447.png)

Is there a setting I'm missing or will it only work if I explicitly write some type of Javascript in the HTML tags?